# Auto complete issue in eclipse Android SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04 to program Android Applications. Since a couple of days, i have got a really weird problem with the auto completion feature: when i hit ctr + space , eclipse shows all the possibilities like it always did. But if i choose one of them and hit enter , it often doesn't do anything (and in some cases it acts normally). For example if i type 'find' and hit ctr + space , it shows the possibilities 'findViewById()' and 'FindListener'. If i choose Findlistener, the auto completion works, but if i choose findViewById , eclipse doesn't do anything, except (sometimes) throwing the following exception in the Linux terminal:

```
Exception in thread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:533)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:323)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.MementoTokenizer.nextToken(MementoTokenizer.java:112)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModel.getHandleFromMemento(JavaModel.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getHandleFromMemento(JavaElement.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.create(JavaCore.java:3006)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.create(JavaCore.java:2981)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.Util.getPackageFragment(Util.java:946)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.Util.getClassFile(Util.java:759)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.Util.getUnresolvedJavaElement(Util.java:1527)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.Util.getUnresolvedJavaElement(Util.java:1371)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodBinding.getUnresolvedJavaElement(MethodBinding.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodBinding.getJavaElement(MethodBinding.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.SemanticHighlightings$DeprecatedMemberHighlighting.consumes(SemanticHighlightings.java:1239)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.SemanticHighlightingReconciler$PositionCollector.visit(SemanticHighlightingReconciler.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleName.accept0(SimpleName.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2562)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleType.accept0(SimpleType.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2562)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ClassInstanceCreation.accept0(ClassInstanceCreation.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2562)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.VariableDeclarationFragment.accept0(VariableDeclarationFragment.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.VariableDeclarationStatement.accept0(VariableDeclarationStatement.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Block.accept0(Block.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2562)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.IfStatement.accept0(IfStatement.java:190)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Block.accept0(Block.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2562)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration.accept0(MethodDeclaration.java:504)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AnonymousClassDeclaration.accept0(AnonymousClassDeclaration.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2562)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ClassInstanceCreation.accept0(ClassInstanceCreation.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodInvocation.accept0(MethodInvocation.java:245)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2562)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ExpressionStatement.accept0(ExpressionStatement.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Block.accept0(Block.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2562)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration.accept0(MethodDeclaration.java:504)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration.accept0(TypeDeclaration.java:484)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit.accept0(CompilationUnit.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.SemanticHighlightingReconciler.reconcilePositions(SemanticHighlightingReconciler.java:371)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.SemanticHighlightingReconciler.reconciled(SemanticHighlightingReconciler.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.reconciled(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1664)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconciled(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:212)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconciled(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:164)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.initialProcess(MonoReconciler.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler.initialProcess(JavaReconciler.java:406)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:173)
```

After creating a new workspace and starting a new android project, the following exception is written into the terminal:

```
Exception in thread "AsyncQueryWorker" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: libcore/io/Libcore
        at android.os.Process.myTid(Process.java:670)
        at android.os.HandlerThread_Delegate.run(HandlerThread_Delegate.java:69)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: libcore.io.Libcore
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
        ... 3 more
```

```
The things i've already tried to solve the problem: 
-create a new workspace
-reinstall the Android plugin
-reinstall eclipse
-change the settings of the content assist and then restore the defaults
-reinstalling all the packages from the Android SDK manager
```

Does anyone have an idea how i can fix this problem? I would greatly appreciate any suggestion. Thank you

Comment: I was just about to suggest dumping the old workspace and create a new one. With ADT plugin I am rarely able to keep the same workspace for more than 2 days before numerous problems prevents me from working at all. Seems like it didn't fix your particular issue.